# Install client certificate for IIS App Pool account

Tags: web-services, security, iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

**Scenario:**

- A client calls WebService A on the LAN. WebService A is running under an App Pool with Identity "Network Service".
- WebService A does some work, prepares to call WebService B.
- WebService B requires a client cert (*.cer) and SSL.
- WebService A is on a dedicated Windows 2003 server.
- Everything works in the Dev environment as it should (but the developer with Administrator privileges is always logged on locally (no surprise!).
- The certificates are stored on disk at `C:\MyCertificates\`
- The certificate is being applied at runtime successfully in Dev with this snippet: `myWebService.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath));`

**Problem:**
WebService A is calling WebService B, and the returned exception is:

> The request failed with HTTP status
>   403: Forbidden

This really means that the certificate was not sent in the request to WebService B.

I am under the assumption that installing this cert into the browser is not a solution. The browser settings typically are per-user, and I need to give the certificate to the user whose credentials the web service is running under. (e.g. Network Service, System, or whatever is in the IIS AppPool settings).

**Question:** How can I grant access or association to my certificate living at the specified directory location to the Network Service or other non-user account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Microsoft knowledgebase article may be of use:

> [How to call a Web service by using a client certificate for authentication in an ASP.NET Web application (MS KB901183)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/901183)

Your web service 'A' would effectively be the ASP.NET application calling the web service as described in the article.